# AssertionError: Different sizes of images, error while I divide image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to calculate asymmetry of the region of interest of an image. I got the center and I was able to divide the image according to the medium of the region of interest. However, when using split images to compare asymmetry between them, I get the following error.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
from PIL import Image
IMD = 'IMD036'
thresh = cv2.imread(IMD+'.png',0)
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
print (len(contours))
cnt = contours

for i in range (len(cnt)):
    (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt[i])
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    cv2.circle(thresh,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)
    print ('Circle: ' + str(i) + ' - Center: ' + str(center) + ' - Radius: ' + str(radius))

x, y = center
print(x)
img1 = thresh[:, :x]
img2 = thresh[:, x:]

cv2.imwrite('face1.png', img1
cv2.imwrite('face2.png', img2)

i1 = Image.open("face1.png")
i2 = Image.open("face2.png")
assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."

pairs = zip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
    # for gray-scale jpegs
    dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
else:
    dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))

ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
print ("Difference (percentage):"+ str((dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents))
```

Error exit:

```
AssertionError: Different sizes.
```

Exit images divided:
**324x575** size: *68,7kb*

[image]

**439x575** size: *68,9kb*

[image]

```
i1.mode = L i2.mode = L
```

Comment: Did you look at the values of `i1.mode` and `i2.mode`?

Comment: @Cris to `i1.mode`  = L
and to `i2.mode`  = RGB

Comment: That's weird. Do `face1.png` and `face2.png` actually get saved? OpenCV doesn't error out if things go wrong, I believe. Delete the files, run your program, and see if the files are actually read in. Note you're overwriting `i1` and `i2`, maybe you should try using different variable names there too. Check that the image files are created, and that they're being read in.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did as recommended, I changed the names of the variables, I deleted the program again. He created two images with different sizes, because the region of interest is not in the center of the image. I updated the question with the new code and new images.

Comment: If you split at the center of the minimum enclosing circle, you can't expect the image to be split exactly in half to make two images of the same size.  The center of the object is not necessarily at the center of the image.  So, isn't the "error" really that it shouldn't assert that `i1.size == i2.size`?

Comment: @Um 
I understood, it worked.